# How to write code(web application) that find wifi printers automatically from ipad when tap print icon

Tags: ios, ipad, web-applications, printers, airprint

Am creating a iPad version web page. when trying to see possible ways to connect ipad and printer via wifi many of the sites says without air print it is not possible. All i need to know is,

1) is it possible to connect iPad and printer through WiFi with out air print?

2) how to make my app to find printers automatically and connect to printers and take print through code?

3) which is the best place(site) to find codes regarding this problems?

4) what are the ways to connect iPad and printer via WiFi other than air print?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it's not as simple as finding the printer then printing to it. ALL printers require driver software to be installed on the spooling device which act AS part of the OSI model and are a key part of communication between the printer and the application.